# How to fix duplicate class issue when importing flutter modules in build gradle inside android?

Tags: android, flutter, aar

I have trying to import two flutter modules in the android build.gradle file as shown below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techy.nateshmbhat.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url '/Users/nateshmbhat/Desktop/flutter-android-bridge/flutter_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
        }
        maven{
            url '/Users/nateshmbhat/Desktop/flutter-android-bridge/flutter_module2/build/host/outputs/repo'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}

dependencies {

    debugImplementation 'com.techy.nateshmbhat.flutter_module:flutter_debug:1.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.example.flutter_module2:flutter_debug:1.0'

}
```

But during gradle build I get the following error :

```
Duplicate class io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant found in modules flutter_debug-1.0-runtime.jar (com.example.flutter_module2:flutter_debug:1.0) and flutter_debug-1.0-runtime.jar (com.techy.nateshmbhat.flutter_module:flutter_debug:1.0)
```

How do I fix this duplication issue ? Is there a way to exclude the clashing class from the flutter build process itself so that it doesn't clash when included ?

Comment: have you found a way to add two Flutter modules to Android?

Comment: nope not directly

Comment: This issue is fixed ?? same issue im facing

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do it directly. It's an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707) on Flutter repo.

The author of this issue mentioned a workaround for this (quoting from the author: [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707#issue-488326165)):

> Import both modules as packages of a third module, here called
> `umbrella`.
>
> **umbrella/pubspec.yaml**
>
> ```yaml
> dependencies:
>   first_module:
>     path: ../flutter_modules/first_module
>   second_module:
>     path: ../flutter_modules/second_module
> ```
>
> Clearly this is not desirable and it feels pretty hacky. In addition,
> it adds one more layer to the import process and depending on the
> method you use, you'll have to repeat some steps as the need for
> modules change.